# Customize order of a list in Drupal 6

Tags: views

I have a list of links that are all displayed as one list.
They are currently sorted by 'Title' asc.

I would like to customize the order of this list.

How can I do that in Drupal 6.

Example:

- A1
- B1
- C1

But I want instead to have (not sorted or organized in any specific order):

- A1
- C1
- B1

This is my backend interface in Drupal 6:

[image]

Thank you for your help!
Izumi.

Comment: If this question is related to Drupal 6, please share in details how you are generating the list. Are you using views module to generate the list of content?

Comment: Thank you @JayendraKainthola - I added a screenshot of the backend in Drupal 6. Thank you for your help!
Izumi.

Comment: Do you mean you want random order, or a specificorder that is not alphabetic but based on something else?

Comment: If you want "not any specific order", it will default to database order, and it is usually order of creation. There is no such thing as "no order" - machines can't work like that. There is default order or the order you set, so if default is not OK for you, tell us what do you want. It *may* be a random order as @rooby said.

Comment: Thank you @rooby and Molot - the list includes departments and sub-departments. I want the sub-departments to be displayed under the departments. But there is no way to distinguish what item in the list is a department or a sub-department. I was hoping that there was a to sort the order manually. But I understand it might not be possible in Drupal 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [draggable views](https://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) module should be pretty much what you need.

> The DraggableViews module can be used to organize simple lists and complex structures via drag n' drop. The configuration is quite easy as you just have to access the style-plugin settings.

Here's a [tutorial](https://drupal.org/node/283498). Look specifically at the part that's headed as **Create a sorting interface for views**:

> With DraggableViews you can create a "sorting interface" that will allow users to sort the result of the view using Drupal's built in drag and drop functionality. The simple overview for this is:
>
> - Create a view
> - Create one display that will be the actual list displayed to visitors
> - Create another display that will act as a "sorting interface" and be used to sort the result of the view

Don't forget to set the access parameters for the sorting interface, maybe limit it to specific roles, otherwise anyone can come in and change the order of your lists :P

Answer (score 0):

In your own custom module implement [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/docs!docs.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/6) and alter the view's result in the following manner:

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'my_view') {
    // for example reverse the result
    $view->result = array_reverse($view->result);
  }
}
```

Use devel module and namely the [dpm](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/6) function to test your code before and after. It is very handy.
Hope this helps.